# How to insert a section title with its number in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, numbering

I want to automatically insert the section title with its number in each beamer frame (or in just some of them). How can we achieve this?

Comment: `\insertsection` gives you the title of the current section, `\thesection` the number

Comment: thank you very much! samcarter But how  to get this done automatically (if possible )  in each frame ?

Comment: I did it by reading the documentation. Just look through the themes and pick one you like.

Comment: @BoukhouldaHafid depends on where you want to put the information. It would be helpfull if you would provide a minimal working example

Comment: `\section{section one}

\begin{frame}

1. section one
....
....
\end{frame}

\section{section two}

\begin{frame}

2. section two
....
.....

\end{frame}`

I want this to be done **automatically** for **all** the frames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\thesection.~\insertsection~\insertframetitle}

\makeatletter
\CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{section one} 
\begin{frame}
blub
\end{frame} 

\section{section two} 
\begin{frame}
blub
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the Latex beamer document class, the frame title (and subtitle) for a frame are defined in [beamerouterthemedefault](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty).

To override the definition, you can copy the definition into your Latex file and enclose it with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

For example, to add the section number before the title, change the following line and add `\thesection.~\insertsection:~` before `\insertframetitle`:

```
\strut\thesection.~\insertsection:~\insertframetitle\strut\par%
```

**Full Example:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{default}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{customized}[1][left]
{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
    % The following line was modified to insert
    % section number (\thesection)
    % and section title (\insertsection).
    \strut\thesection.~\insertsection:~\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]%
         {framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Some text.
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Latex beamer frame with section number and title]